# How to script a web application served from ARM board (like Raspberry Pi)?

Tags: webserver, development, raspberry-pi, arm

What would you suggest as a backend for web application served from a small ARM board like Raspberry Pi running linux?

My idea is to control the ARM board via a web interface. This would involve serving up bunch of static html/css/js that contains a javascript app that runs in browser client-side, and then accepting HTTP requests and translating them to system calls, sometimes returning the output of those system calls.

Normally I would set up either a Ruby or Node.js stack and hack away, but I think that would be too taxing on resources in this case. In fact, I would like to leave as much resources as possible to other processes that would run on this board.

So, what would you suggest so set that translation up with? Languages, server software, frameworks? What do, for example, routers use for serving up their admin interfaces?

Comment: I don't think this is really on topic for Super User, but I'm not sure if it belongs on Server Fault, Pro Webmasters, or Stack Overflow.  (I'm guessing due to the small scale it might not fit at either of the first two, but it feels less on topic for SO...)  It is a good *question*.

Answer (score 0):

A fair number of routers and such use CGI scripts to do that, you can render the page as html and such with it.  Additionally, it can act as the apache server (See Python's: [CGIHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html))

My favorite is Python but I know Perl is huge in this too.  It will definitely be slightly heavier than raw HTML/JS since that's all client side - but it'll allow you to work with the hardware a ton.

CGI's can work with Python, Perl, Bash, and a few others that escape me.  Funny you ask because I am currently working on one built on Python for my MicroPC as well (something similar to a RPi).